# Login screen hangs, login only after restarting X

Tags: 22.04, login, xorg

For a while, I experience regularly that the login screen on Ubuntu Studio 22.04 hangs, just a few seconds after it has appeared. That means: I can move the mouse pointer, but the cursor freezes and I cannot enter my password. I cannot open the virtual keyboard either. When I Ctrl-F2 and back to Ctrl-F1 the screen remains black, with the mouse pointer. My work-around it to log in on another non-graphical screen. When I then init 4, followed by init 5, the login screen always works without any problem. It seems as if the second start of X follows a slightly different procedure than the first.

I removed the Xorg.conf file because I read I would not need it, but that didn't do the trick. I checked the /var/log/boot files but could not see any warnings or errors that seemed relevant.

Has anyone any idea how to avoid this problem? Thanks in advance, y'all!